# I don't understand what's wrong with this code

Tags: vb.net, forms, copy, directory

Can you Please help me with this code? And Please do not give me a negative mark!!

```
If Not Directory.Exists("C:\Libraries\Documents\Backup - Advanced_Website_Blocker  Folder") Then
          Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Libraries\Documents\Backup -  Advanced_Website_Blocker Folder")
    End If
    Dim FileToCopy As String
    Dim NewCopy As String

    FileToCopy = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
    NewCopy = "C:\Libraries\Documents\Backup - Advanced_Website_Blocker Folder\hosts"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) = True Then

        System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)
        MsgBox("File Copied")

    Else : MsgBox("No Folder Found!")

    End If
```

Comment: What problems are you having with it ? Errors, unexpected results ???

Comment: No, you need to _tell us_ what the problem is, what exceptions you are getting.  Then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please see and try this:

http://www.macoratti.net/d111103.htm

also:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/327619/vb-net-how-to-copy-file-from-one-Directory-to-anot

Comment: Answers with links only are discouraged here on SO because the links may not be valid in the future.

Comment: Sorry!!! I'll try not to put link to other forums, but I think that I can put the links of SO. Right?

Answer (score 0):

```
 FileToCopy = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

is a folder

```
 If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy)
```

is checking for the existince of a file not a folder

Comment: No! Its a File search it in File Explorer C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The file 'C:\Libraries\Documents\Backup - Advanced_Website_Blocker Folder\hosts' already exists.

Comment: OK, look like a problem with if Not try if else ie:                        If Directory.Exists("C:\Libraries\Documents\Backup - Advanced_Website_Blocker  Folder") Then
        else                                                           Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Libraries\Documents\Backup -      Advanced_Website_Blocker Folder")
    End If

Comment: Doesn't work look at it An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The file 'C:\Libraries\Documents\Backup - Advanced_Website_Blocker Folder\hosts' already exists.

Comment: need more info, does the folder actually exist ? , easy way out wrap the create line in a try catch bit of cheat but get's the job done

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the existence of the file and if it exists, overwrite it.  You can use the overload of the File.Copy method that overwrites the file:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the libraries to be imported, see the example code below:

```
' For File.Exists, Directory.Exists 

Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections

Public Class RecursiveFileProcessor

    Public Overloads Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)
        Dim path As String
        For Each path In args
            If File.Exists(path) Then
                ' This path is a file.
                ProcessFile(path)
            Else
                If Directory.Exists(path) Then
                    ' This path is a directory.
                    ProcessDirectory(path)
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path)
                End If
            End If
        Next path
    End Sub 'Main


    ' Process all files in the directory passed in, recurse on any directories 
    ' that are found, and process the files they contain.
    Public Shared Sub ProcessDirectory(ByVal targetDirectory As String)
        Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)
        ' Process the list of files found in the directory.
        Dim fileName As String
        For Each fileName In fileEntries
            ProcessFile(fileName)

        Next fileName
        Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
        ' Recurse into subdirectories of this directory.
        Dim subdirectory As String
        For Each subdirectory In subdirectoryEntries
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory)
        Next subdirectory

    End Sub 'ProcessDirectory

    ' Insert logic for processing found files here.
    Public Shared Sub ProcessFile(ByVal path As String)
        Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", path)
    End Sub 'ProcessFile
End Class 'RecursiveFileProcessor
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1